# Proper Delete in MySQL Using Join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete data from a table in MySQL, but before I execute the command I want to make sure that I am doing it right. I'm looking to delete all rows with a storeID > 5000000 and cannot match to any item in the deals table. Below is my query:

```
DELETE FROM stores s 
LEFT JOIN deals sd 
ON s.storeID = sd.store_ID 
WHERE storeID > 5000000 
AND sd.dealID IS NULL;
```

Will the above query only delete the rows in the stores table and not affect the deals table?

Comment: what happens when you try?

Comment: It's a production table, so I don't really want to try without being sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned with the query deleting extra stuff from your production table I'd suggest spinning up a development instance and replicating the database schema.  If possible take a full dump of the production database and import it into your development/test system.  That way you can test your queries and know for certain their outcome.

If you you want a dump of the database or even just the databases schema you can use `mysqldump` to generate these.

I don't think your query will remove anything from the deals table, but I would recommend you check to be 100% certain.  Is this not going to leave you with rows in the deals table that reference a storeid that isn't in the stores table?